# BPOSB and EBELP do not have compatible types in CDS association

Tags: abap, cds

I'm new to CDS and I'm trying to make my first view.

The thing is that when I try the following code I receive the error:

> Association _Purchase_Order: BPOSB and EBELP do not have a compatible
> type.

Is it possible to make a cast on any field of the association to make it work?

Thanks in advance

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'YMM_VFRET'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'Merchandise distribution view'
define view YMM_FRET 
as select from fret as Collective_Purchase
association [1..*] to ekpo as _Stock_Transfer_Order 
on $projection.blnra = _Stock_Transfer_Order.ebeln and $projection.bposa = _Stock_Transfer_Order.ebelp
association [1] to ekpo as _Purchase_Order       
on $projection.blnrb = _Purchase_Order.ebeln and $projection.bposb = _Purchase_Order.ebelp
  {
  key Collective_Purchase.blnrb,
  key Collective_Purchase.bposb,
  key Collective_Purchase.blnra,
  key Collective_Purchase.bposa,
  _Stock_Transfer_Order,
  _Purchase_Order
}
```

Comment: you can add one layer of CDS view on top of the database table selection , convert the numc to char6 to have a calculated column, associate the view on the calculated column

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

`BPOSB` in `FRET` table has type NUMC(6)

`EBELP` in `EKPO` table has type NUMC(**5**)

According to the [type comparison matrix](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abencds_cond_expr_types.htm) you should have exact matching between RHS and LHS type length.

[image]

As per the [rules](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abencds_cond_expr_on_assoc.htm) for conditionals in `ON` clause of the association:

> No path expressions or other expressions or function calls can be specified.

So you can't do neither `CAST( num1 AS NUMC( N ) )`, nor `SUBSTRING`. Neither for RHS nor for LHS operand.

I see no solution here except rebuilding your view in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it.

I made two CDS views.

The first one had all the FRET fields but used RIGHT and CAST to convert BPOSB  and BPOSA to NUMC type.

```
DEFINE VIEW YMM_FRET_0 AS SELECT FROM FRET {
KEY MANDT,
KEY BTYPB,
KEY BLNRB,
KEY CAST( RIGHT( BPOSB, 5 ) AS ABAP.NUMC( 5 ) ) AS BPOSB, // <-- 
KEY BTYPA,
KEY BLNRA,
KEY CAST( RIGHT( BPOSA, 5 ) AS ABAP.NUMC( 5 ) ) AS BPOSA, // <--
...
```

The second used the first view and that resolved the issue.